# How to use evince to open PDF accessed through remote ssh?

Tags: pdf, gui, evince, powershell

It is extremely likely this question comes from a major misunderstanding, but I will explain what I am trying to do/have done. I am also not fully sure this is a Linux/Unix issue.

My goal is to view a pdf on a remote computer that I am accessing with ssh -X. For context, I am doing this on Windows 11 Powershell.

(EDIT) This is on my local laptop using Windows 11 Powershell. I want this display to be on my local laptop and the pdf is on the remote computer which uses Linux. I installed WSL while trying to figure this out, but I don't think I've used it for anything.

I started with using `evince Filename.pdf` as I've done on my school's lab computers, but it gives me `Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

I've tried setting a display with `export DISPLAY='IP:0.0'` because some StackExchange comments said to try that.

I called `xhost +` a bunch. I don't know what that does, but comments said do that.

My question is simply how to use Evince to open this PDF file. I'm not specifically tied to Evince.

I just want to view the PDF and I'm unsure of the process.

It's worth mentioning that I have sudo permissions.

Comment: Please clarify: Are you sitting on a local machine running Windows? The remote system you are connecting to is Linux? Is WSL involved? Do you want the PDF to appear on the screen of the remote machine or on your local machine?

Comment: @Hermann I added this in an edit, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to open the `.pdf` file using the default pdf viewer on the remote linux machine. And according to you the display manager is X11. The command to open any file with it's system default is to use the following command:

```
$ xdg-open [filename]
```

For your case it would be:

```
$ xdg-open Filename.pdf
```

I think that would open the file in remote window on your local machine.

Comment: This answer does not address the fact that OP needs an X11 server on his Windows machine and needs to configure X11 forwarding. Can be done, but is not trivial. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2